React renders different AG-Grid html in chrome vs firefox
The Ag grid library config we use dynamically applies the editable class to a column / cell. In chrome, the editable class is applied correctly. In firefox, it is not applied. What could be the reason for this?
Chrome css class of a cell (contains needed 'editable' class):
ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-normal-height ag-cell-wrap-text table-cell numeric-cell editable ag-cell-value ag-cell-focus ag-cell-range-selected ag-cell-range-selected-1 ag-cell-range-single-cell ag-cell-range-handle
Firefox css class of a cell:
ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-normal-height ag-cell-wrap-text table-cell numeric-cell ag-cell-value ag-cell-focus ag-cell-range-selected ag-cell-range-selected-1 ag-cell-range-single-cell ag-cell-range-handle
